# Websphere. Authentificate user of web-appliaction without password

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, websphere, jaas

I'm newbie with Websphere AS. Starting learning JAAS. Need write login-module which can authentificate user without entering password. Want also to get all roles from external storage (e.g. DB).

Wrote login-module. Added it into WEB_INBOUND as REQURED at first place. Other login modules marked as OPTIONAL.

Have next troubles:

1. Basic auth popup always comes at first time. Want ommit this if user is aunteficated by my login module.
2. If other login modules aren't marked as OPTIONAL commit-method isn't called. What can I do with this?
3. User is not authentificated as I relized. Why? How should I fix it?
4. How can I add queried roles for user inside login module?

Login module listing:

```
        //imports

    public class SimpleModule implements LoginModule {

                    private Subject subject;
                    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
                    private Map<String, ?> sharedState;

                    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                                                   Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
                                   this.subject = subject;
                                   this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
                                   this.sharedState = sharedState;
                    }

                    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
                                   System.out.println("login called");
                                   return true;
                    }

                    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
                                   System.out.println("Commit called");
                                   // set username
                                   WSPrincipal wsPrincipalImpl = new WSPrincipalImpl("user");
                                   subject.getPrincipals().add(wsPrincipalImpl);
                                   return true;
                    }

                    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
                                   return true;
                    }

                    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
                                   return true;
                    }
    }
```

web.xml listing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
      <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <security-constraint>
            <display-name>Constraint</display-name>
            <web-resource-collection>
                  <web-resource-name>secrets</web-resource-name>
                  <description />
                  <url-pattern>/page.html</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                  <role-name>user-role</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>

      <security-role>
            <role-name>user-role</role-name>
      </security-role>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to switch to TAI instead of LoginModule. It is much easier to write, configure and integrate with WAS security infrastructure than LoginModule.